# Imbalanced Dataset in R - ROSE package

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I'm working in 'German Credit Risk' dataset, and noticed that target variable is imbalanced.
I tried to use the package `ROSE`, though it changed the predictors variables.

```
ds<- data.frame(read.csv("credit.csv",header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE))
View(ds)
library(ROSE)
ds1 <- ROSE(CreditStatus ~ ., data = ds, seed = 1)$data
dim(ds1)
View(ds1)
```

[image: 1]

I'd like to know how to fix it.

[image: 2]

I tried to find another package, but I didn't manage

Comment: Is German Credit Risk data set the one found in [UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+%28German+Credit+Data%29), also in Kaggle?

Comment: Yes, but I'm doing in R

Comment: Over-sampling techniques such as ROSE or SMOTE will always change the predictors, they act by sampling from a *space* defined by the predictors, not by sampling from the predictors themselves.